# AngularJS Directives not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS in a project of mine, and I wanted to try creating directives. I already followed several tutorials and I can't see where I'm doing it wrong. Even worst, it doesn't shows up any error or warning message, but it also does not executes the directive's function. Right now, my code is pretty much this:

```
angular.module('components', []).directive('ngxOnshow', function() {
   return {
          restrict: 'A',
          link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                        console.log("hello world")
                        //Resto do código da função
          }  
   };
});
var module = angular.module('app', ['components']);
```

In the body of the HTML page I have this:

```
<body ng-autobind ng-app="app">
```

But then, when I use the directive, it does not work.

```
<div ng-show="showApp == true" ngx-onshow="showAppBar()">
</div>
```

The rest of the application works just fine, the bindings, the default directives, everything except this. Perhaps I'm missing something?

Thanks,
Scorch :)

Comment: It prints "hello world" to the console for me...

Comment: Your error must be somewhere else. I've copied and pasted your exact code into a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/ZDPTJ/1/) and I see "hello world" in the console.

Comment: Did you remember to add the file with the directive code to your index.html? Sorry, but I had to ask - forgotten that a couple times myself ;) I'm really just assuming you have all that code in a single.js file at the moment though, so it's likely something else. Just a control question :)

Comment: Yes, I have. The javascript in the rest of the file works just fine. Maybe the bug is with the Firebug? Is there any other way to check that out without console? I've tried alert and it didn't work either. Also, I've checked with the Firefox console to make sure the problem wasn't something with firebug, and it said that theuse of console log functions had been desactivated by a script on that page. Is it firebug or another script in my page doing that?

Comment: What is the directive supposed to do?  I.e., when you say "it does not work", what exactly is not working?  Where is showAppBar() defined?  When do you want function showAppBar() to run?

Comment: The directive is supposed to execute the specified function when the element is shown (from hiding to show). But that is not part of the code I posted. The showAppBar() function is defined in the controler. WHat I mean with not Working is that the link function is not running. I suppose that function shoould run once for each element "attached", right? :)

Comment: I believe (not certain) that the link function will run whether or not the element in which the directive is in is shown or hidden.  If you want showAppBar() to run when showApp is true, $watch showApp in your link function, and run scope.showAppBar() in the watch callback function.  Then you can remove the ng-show directive.

Comment: I decided to go with an isolated scope instead -- see my posted answer.

Comment: Finally found what was messing up. In fact, it was a noob mistake: I had a ng-app in the html tag too, and never noticed, and that was blocking the ng-app in the body tag. Really sorry for taking your time, guys. Thanks, it's working now. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use '&' to allow a directive to execute an expression/function defined in the parent scope.  $observe an interpolated isolate scope attribute  (i.e., one defined with '@' that contains `{{}}`) to determine when it changes:

```
myApp.directive('ngxOnshow', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      showApp: '@',
      ngxOnshow: '&'
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log("inside link function")
      attrs.$observe('showApp', function (newValue) {
        newValue === "true" && scope.ngxOnshow()
      })
    }
  };
});
```

newValue is compared with `"true"` not `true` because interpolated values are always strings.

HTML:

```
<div ng-show="showApp == true" show-app="{{showApp}}" ngx-Onshow="showAppBar()">
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/aRQ6p/).

Answer (score 7):

Most of directive errors are displayed in the console, just enable logging:

```
app.config(function($logProvider){
    $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
});
```

Thus you'd have no need to guess why directive is't working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know what the directive should do, because all you have is a `console.log`. But since you pass a function to the `ngxOnshow` argument, I suppose you want to execute it. You need to tell the directive to execute the function from the parent with `scope` set to `&`:

```
angular.module('components', []).directive('ngxOnshow', function() {
   return {
          restrict: 'A',
          scope: {
            ngxOnshow: '&'
          },
          link: function(scope, element, attrs){
                        console.log("hello world")
                        //Resto do código da função
          }  
   };
});
```

Comment: Hi and thanks, I didn't knew that. But unfortunately, the problem is not that because it still does not work and it still does not show the log message. :(